# I am trying to upload file to firebase which is pdf in swift but getting following error

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

**During downloading I get url successfully but following error while uploading**

```
2022-02-10 23:50:56.154941-0800 QuranApp[2202:419266] CFURLResourceIsReachable failed because it was passed a URL which has no scheme
Optional(Error Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13000 "File at URL: /Users/apple/Downloads/arabic.pdf is not reachable. Ensure file URL is not a directory, symbolic link, or invalid url." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=File at URL: /Users/apple/Downloads/arabicquran.pdf is not reachable. Ensure file URL is not a directory, symbolic link, or invalid url., NSUnderlyingError=0x282b187b0 {Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=262 "The file couldn’t be opened because the specified URL type isn’t supported."}})
```

**Code**

```
 let url = URL(string: "/Users/apple/Downloads/arabicquran.pdf")
        
          let fileextension = url?.pathExtension
          let filename = "testing.\(fileextension)"
          
         self.storage.child("QuranURL/\(filename)").putFile(from: url!, metadata: nil,completion: {url, error in
             
             guard error == nil else {
                 print("No URl uploaded : \(error)")
                 return
             }
            
              print("Uploaded : \(url)")

            })
```

Comment: That is the wrong init for a local file, use [init(fileURLWithPath:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url/3126800-init) instead

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I have used init(fileURLWithPath: "myurl") but still same error I'm getting

Comment: Does the error message really say the _exact_ same thing?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes exactly the same thing

Comment: If I change the URL it still comes up with the same error

Comment: That's strange that the error is the same when the url is different. Could you do `print(url.absoluteString)` and add the result?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I can print url there is nothing wrong with that but I am curious about error it remains the same even if I change the url.....

Comment: I meant that you should share the result of doing the print here